# Difference Between " " and [ ] in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have written a simple program to reverse a string but I am getting different result with i write `a = ""` and when I write `a = []`. Please can someone help me explain why this happens:

Input is:

```
"Argument goes here"
```

**1st way**

```
 a= []
 for i in range(( len(text)-1,-1,-1):
   a+= text[i]  
 return a
```

Output is: `['e', 'r', 'e', 'h', ' ', 's', 'e', 'o', 'g', ' ', 't', 'n', 'e', 'm', 'u', 'g', 'r', 'A']`

**2nd way**

```
a = ""
for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
    a += text[len(text) - i]  
return a
```

Output is: `ereh seog tnemugrA`

Comment: How did you even learn that `[]` and `""` are valid python code without learning what they *mean*?

Comment: I am using "learn as you work approach".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a = []` instantiates an empty list. When you add to a list with the `+` operator, you are performing a **list extend**. In other words, you are extending your list by the extra character. Note that since you are adding one character at a time, this has the same *effect* as `list.append`.

`a = ''` instantiates an empty string. When you add to a string with the `+` operator, you are performing a **string concatenation**.

The results will therefore be different. The first will give you a `list` object with reversed elements. The second will give you a `str` object with characters reversed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response .

Answer (score 1):

**@avik**, do not do in that way. You can use the below approach to reverse string.

> `[]` denotes the empty list and `""` denotes an empty string.
>
> 1. In first case, you are adding each character of your string from end to list `a` using `a += text[i]`. So you got a list of characters. Here you can use `' '.join(a)` to get a reversed string before returning `a`.
> 2. In second case, you are concatenating each character of string from end so you got a reversed string.
>
> **Reverse string**:
>
> s = "Argument goes here"
>
> reversed_s = "".join(list(reversed(s)))

```
>>> s = "Argument goes here"
>>>
>>> reversed(s)
<reversed object at 0x00000275F29B9F60>
>>> list(reversed(s))
['e', 'r', 'e', 'h', ' ', 's', 'e', 'o', 'g', ' ', 't', 'n', 'e', 'm', 'u', 'g', 'r', 'A']
>>>
>>> "".join(list(reversed(s)))
'ereh seog tnemugrA'
>>>
```

Comment: He wasn't asking how to reverse a string.  He was asking why he's getting two different results from his programs.